# django channels how to send json to all users of group

Tags: django, redis, django-channels

i have a problem with the group_send function. If I try to run it it doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't even run. I'm using the function with django channels with redis server. It should send me the json but nothing is received from the group_send while with the self.send it arrives. Can someone help me?

```
class Accettazioni(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):

        self.room = 'test'
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(self.room, self.channel_name)

        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):

        user = self.scope["user"]
        id_user = user.id
        id_postazione = self.scope['session']['ID']
        print(user, id_user, id_postazione)

        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        print(text_data_json)
        if 'prossimo_cliente' in text_data_json:

            prossima_prenotazione = richiesta_prossimo_cli()
            prenotazione_in_PresaInCarico(id_user, id_postazione, prossima_prenotazione)

            if prossima_prenotazione is not None:
                json_pronto = impacchetta_json(prossima_prenotazione)
                self.send(json.dumps({'prossima_prenotazione': json_pronto}))

                async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(self.room, {'prossima_prenotazione': json_pronto})

            else:
                self.send(json.dumps({'prossimo_cliente': 'KO'}))
```

i tried without the async_to_sync function too but it still doesn't work. I expect the json to be sent to all users who are connected to this consumer.how can i solve?